# reading multiple inputs to one position in the array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

im curretly working on a question wherein i need to take multiple inputs for each position in the array.

size is 7 so i need to take values more than 1 for each position like below

2 3

3 1

1 2 4 5

3

3 2

7

6 0

please find my program below:  the method i was trying but in vain.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int b1, x=0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter no. of members in a team: ");
    b1 = in.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[b1];
    System.out.println("enter the members of the team");
    for (int i=0; i<b1;i++) {
        arr[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
```

kindly help on this guys. thanks.

Comment: it looks like each cell in the array should be an array

Comment: yes you are right.. how can i go about with that ?

Comment: Your code doesn't really match what you're saying. You ask for the number of member in a team, then ask for the members. Why do you need the second dimension then?

Comment: sorry..forget the naming convention.. that is different.. ignore that... what i actually need is the quesion i wrote.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you need to read seven teams into an array, having members of each team in one array? Can you give us the exact wording of your assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in java for strings called split that could help you here.

```
String[] temparr = "5 7 12 8".split(" ");
```

That will create an array with values

```
temparr[0] = "5";
temparr[1] = "7";
```

a.s.o.

Then you could translate these with valueof on integer.

```
int[][] arr = new int[x][];
arr[1] = new int[arr.length];
int i = 0;
for(String s : arr) {
   arr[1][i] = Integer.valueof(s);
   i++;
}
```

If you don't know the number of inputs then you could use an ArrayList of Objects instead.

```
 public class Team {
    public int teamsize;
    public int[] team_members;
 }

 List<Team> teamList = new ArrayList<Team>();

 Team t = new Team();
 t.teamsize = …
 t.team_members = new int[];
 t.team_members[0] = …
 teamList.add(t);
```

Comment: How does that help with storing an array of integer arrays?

Comment: what if i need "all" "in" in arr[1] ?

Comment: Hope my example gives you an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: yes.. thank u.. this might help me.. will get back to u if i face any problems. thanks again